# Adding a number to midpoint af an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How do you add a number to the midpoint to an array (no arraylists) so no numbers are overwriten but the last number will not be in the array. My code:

```
 int midpoint = length/2;
 array[midpoint] = 4;
 for (int i = midpoint; i < array.length -1; i++)
 {
     array[i] = array[i+1];
 }          
 displayArray(array);
```

Comment: yes adding the number to midpoint while moving all the other numbers to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift all the items from the midpoint to the right, and then add the midpoint.

If i were you i'd iterate in reverse.

```
for (int i = array.length - 1; i > midpoint; i--)
{
    array[i] = array[i-1];
}

array[midpoint] = somenumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to efficiently shift the elements:

```
System.arraycopy(array, midpoint, array, midpoint + 1, array.length - midpoint - 1);
array[midpoint] = 4;
```

The problem with your current approach is that you irretrievably modify the elements before moving them into their final positions.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
int midpoint = array.length/2;

for (int i = array.length-1 ; i> midpoint; i--) { 
  array[i] = array[i-1]; 
}

array[midpoint] = 4; 
displayArray(array);
```