# shifting numbers in array after deleting midpoint

Tags: java, arrays

I am using an array that inputs a numbers from a file. I have to delete the midpoint number and shift all other numbers after the midpoint to the left to fill the space. This works unless the array has not enougth numbers to fill the array so it just keeps prints out the last number twice instead of once. How can I get it to stop printin when there are no numbers left in the file. (Sorry if this sounds complicated)  My code is below

```
        for (int i = mid; i < array.length -1 ; i++){

            array[i] = array[i+1];

        }
```

Comment: Need more context, I think. Can you include the code that's exhibiting the undesired behavior?

Comment: @AlanKrueger sorry what behavior

Comment: Hmm, can't you simply modify the if-sstatement?

Comment: What data type is array? If it's ArrayList, just use remove() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)
If it's a linked list, just remove a node and re-wire the link from the previous item.

Comment: Well, an array is a fixed size structure, so this is 'expected behavior'. Your requirements are vague - are you bound to keeping the original array intact? And if so, what value are you supposed to fill onto the end of the array when its elements are shifted?

Comment: @adel how would i modify the if statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a number to midpoint af an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119761/adding-a-number-to-midpoint-af-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

> it just keeps prints out the last number twice instead of once

After you've shifted the elements, presumably you need to actually delete the last element, since it is no longer used. For this, you could use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a homework assignment, don't reinvent the wheel.  `java.utils.ArrayList` already does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Run your loop for `array.length -2`. Because your `Last` and `Second Last` item in array are same. Thats why it is writing it twice.